# Alter all table columns with out white space in between names

Tags: oracle, trim, removing-whitespace

Oracle - Alter all table column names with trim of white space in between names

For suppose column names before alter :

Home number

Mobile number

Local number

After alter column names shall be :

Homenumber

Mobilenumber

Localnumber

I've tried this way: but unable to crack:

```
 UPDATE SA_VW_PHONENUMBER TN SET TN.Column_Name   = TRIM (TN.Column_Name);
```

Answer (score 3):

### Fully automatic way

Use this cursor based DDL hacking - statement concat.

```
BEGIN
   FOR alters IN
   (
      SELECT
        'ALTER TABLE "'||table_name||'" RENAME COLUMN "'||column_name||
         '" TO "'||replace(cols.column_name,' ','')||'"' sql_stmt
      FROM all_tab_cols cols
      WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(column_name,'[[:space:]]')
         AND owner = user --Add real schema name here
      ORDER BY 1
   ) LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( alters.sql_stmt ||';') ;
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE alters.sql_stmt;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

### If you want to use the safe way

As I know you cannot perform a DDL as a dynamic SQL, so you cannot pass variables to the `ALTER TABLE` command, but here is what you can do instead of that.

1. Selecting the occurences:

```
SELECT table_name,column_name,replace(cols.column_name,' ','') as replace_name
  FROM all_tab_cols
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(column_name,'[[:space:]]');
```

2. Use the `ALTER TABLE` DDL command:

```
alter table T_TABLE rename column "COLUMN SPACE" TO "COLUMNNOSPACE";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the REPLACE function

```
 UPDATE SA_VW_PHONENUMBER TN SET TN.Column_Name = REPLACE(TN.Column_Name,' ','')
```